# How to only choose elements in an array with a specific length

Tags: java, arrays, string, random

```
public String[] words={"cat", "dog", "rodeo", "bird", "lookers", "skid");
```

.

```
// Picks a random word from the dictionary, given the length of the word
public String pickWord(int size)
{

}
```

So if a user inputs 4, it randomly chooses a word in the word array with 4 letters, and randomly. I have created a rand variable from the Random class for that. So how do I choose an element in the array with the same number of letters as the number the user inputted.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example method that should work to solve your problem.

```
String[] words;
public String pickWord(int size){
    List ls = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i>words.length;i++){
        if(words[i].length() == size){
            ls.add(words[i]);
        }
    }
    Collections.shuffle(ls);
    if(ls.isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }
    return (String) ls.get(0);
}
```

Comment: Because the Jakkie wants a random character from the array, after finding all of the 4 letter words and adding them to the list taking the 0 slot will always give the first found. So I used a shuffle to make the output random.

Answer (score 1):

You could go really simply and do something like....

```
public String pickWord(int size) {

    List<String> results = Arrays.stream(words).
        filter((String t) -> t.length() == size).
        collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    Collections.shuffle(results);
    return results.isEmpty() ? null : results.get(0);

}
```

Where something like...

```
System.out.println(pickWord(3));
System.out.println(pickWord(4));
System.out.println(pickWord(5));
System.out.println(pickWord(6));
```

Could print something like...

```
cat
skid
rodeo
null
```

Comment: Personally I'd use `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`. `Collectors.toList` makes no guarantee about the mutability of the list.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Cheers, still a NOOB in  this area, hacked to together ;)

Comment: What you wrote works in Java 8 (`toList` does give an `ArrayList` at the moment) but it could break in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Take the strings from the array that have length equal to the input and put those into a list. Generate random int to the size of the list and take random word from the list then.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int maxLen;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
    String[] words = {"cat", "dog", "rodeo", "bird", "lookers", "skid"};
    // Picks a random word from the dictionary, given the length of the word
    System.out.println("Please input the max length of the word.");
    maxLen = sc.nextInt();
    for (String s : words) {
        if (s.length() == maxLen) {
            list.add(s);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(pickWord(list));

}

static String pickWord(ArrayList<String> list) {
    Random rd = new Random();
    int randInt = rd.nextInt(list.size());
    String picked = list.get(randInt);
    return picked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of words with that length. If 0, return null. If 1, return the word. Otherwise use `Random.nextInt(count)` to get number between `0` and `count-1`, then find that word and return it.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a new array with n-length words based on the user input and extract from the new array the random index, since all the elements will fit the specified length.